# String manipulation - Any other efficient way?

Tags: java, string

I had a requirement where i need to insert an escape sequence in a given string variable, at places wherever a **single quotes** (') appears. I tried using **split** method and also **StringTokenizer**, neither one worked out for me. So i developed the below mentioned logic. It also fails in a few scenarios

Can anyone provide me a simplest way to achieve such requirement.?

```
public static String quotesMessage(String message){
    String newMessage="";
    while(message.length()>0){
        if(message.indexOf("'")==0){
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(message.substring(0))){
                message = message.substring(1);
            }
        }else{
            if(message.indexOf("'")!= -1){
                newMessage=newMessage+message.substring(0,message.indexOf("'"))+"\\'";
                message=message.substring(message.indexOf("'"));
            }else{
                newMessage=newMessage+message;
                message="";
            }
        }
    }
    return newMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about this:

```
newMessage.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Or do I misunderstand your requirement?

---

And about the discussions in comments: yes, both `replace()` and `replaceAll()` <s>use Regular Expressions</s> use compiled Patterns internally (but `replace()` uses the flag [`Pattern.LITERAL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL)), interpreting the pattern as literal value, whereas `replaceAll()` (and `replaceFirst()`) both use Regular Expressions. However, the compiled patterns are absolutely identical (in this case). Try it yourself:

```
Pattern literal = Pattern.compile("'",Pattern.LITERAL);
Pattern regular = Pattern.compile("'");
```

Add a breakpoint after these assignments and take a closer look at these two compiled patterns. You will find that all of their field values are identical, so in this case at least, no it doesn't make any difference performance-wise.

Comment: will that replace all the quotes or it ll replace the first quotes.?

Comment: all. The only difference to `replaceAll()` is that it doesn't use regular expressions but simple string replecement.

Comment: thats great.. it works even if i pass a continuous set of quotes..!!

Comment: @jgubby true, but replace() uses Pattern.LITERAL: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replaceAll` method:

```
myString.replaceAll("'", "\\'");
```

Comment: No, don't use `replaceAll()`, use `replace()`. `replaceAll()` uses regular expressions internally, which is totally unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @Sean Great point.  Use `replace` unless you need to search for something more complex than a `CharSequence`.

Comment: @Sean I tried running both `replace` and `replaceAll` 10^12 times, and they seem to have identical performance.  Am I doing it wrong, or are they actually comparably performant?

Comment: @James the regex engine is of course highly optimized, you will probably need much larger numbers to notice the difference. machines are darn fast, these days :-)

Comment: @Sean according to this (https://gist.github.com/809863), `replaceAll` is a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a StringBuilder object rather than manually concatinating the strings. At least you would get some performance improvement out of that if your strings are large.

Answer (score 1):

```
message = message.replaceAll("'", "");
```

Comment: again, `replaceAll()` is overkill, see my comment under James' answer

Answer (score 1):

```
String in = ...
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in.length() + 16);
for (int i=0; i<in.length(); i++) {
    char c = in.charAt(i);
    if (c == '\'') {
        out.append("\\'");
    } else {
        out.append(c);
    }
}

String result = out.toString();
```

Comment: Justification for the random number (16) is to ensure that the StringBuilder is less likely to do a re-allocation for a large string with just one or two instances of the ' character. If you know better about your particular application, you should remove this or change it.

Comment: Verbose because he asked for an efficient implementation, and the String replace() and replaceAll() methods both use a pattern compiled on the spot.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyed Why is this "done properly" vs. a String replace/replaceAll? To justify using this over the much *simpler* methods mentioned would require a performance profile that showed a benefit IMOHO (and an analysis in the appropriate context). There may be an advantage or there may not be an advantage.