# remove special char in java string

Tags: java, string, replace

i have a string like

**String  mydate = jan\10 ;**

but when i print this string i did n't get currect string.
so i want replace the char \ by any other char , like #,@ etc..

how it is possible..

Comment: The java API is extremely helpful, look at it first before posting questions. 90% of the time you will find answers there before posting a question on stackoverflow.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889430/string-manipulation-any-other-efficient-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to shield slash:
`String mydate = "jan\\10" ;`

If you want to replace this char:

`mydate = mydate.replace("\\", "#");//result is jan#10`

Answer (score 1):

```
String myDate = @"jan\10";
String newDate = myDate.replace('\\', '#');
```

Comment: @mac aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh! corrected =P  ... too tired

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "hello\\world";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\", "@"));
```

**output:**

```
hello@world
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydate.replaceAll("\\\\","#");
```

Will replace it. The reason you need four backslashes is that the first argument is a regular expression, which expects backslashes to be escaped, and then java expects the backslashes in strings to be escaped as well, leading to the four backslashes. Alternatively you could just declare your string like

```
String mydate = "jan\\10" ;
```

and have it print normally.

Comment: No, that will throw a runtime exception. Try it.

Comment: @Bart Kiers - Corrected that. Thanks for pointing it out. I had forgotten that `replaceAll()` unlike `replace()` uses regular expressions.